# SELECT unique set of data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

My apologies for such a vague title.

## Background

I have a MySQL table which contains Wordpress blog posts. The table contains posts and their translations, for instance:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------
|post_name|post_type|post_status|post_date           |
 ----------------------------------------------------
|My post  | post    | publish   |2019-05-18 05:00:20 |
 ----------------------------------------------------
| Mi post | post    | publish   |2019-05-18 05:00:20 |
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

Each post and each translation are independent post entries in the table. I am trying to put together a SQL statement that will give me a list of posts and their translated names. The only commonality between translations is the fact posts have the exact same date.

## Current SQL Statement

So far I wrote:

```
SELECT t1.post_name, t2.post_name, t1.post_date 
FROM `posts` t1 LEFT JOIN `posts` t2 ON t1.post_date = t2.post_date 
WHERE t1.post_status='publish' and 
      t1.post_type='post' and 
      t1.post_name<>t2.post_name 
ORDER BY t1.post_date DESC
```

## Output

```
 -----------------------------------------
|post_name|post_name| post_date           |
 -----------------------------------------
|My post  | Mi post | 2019-05-18 05:00:20 |
 -----------------------------------------
| Mi post | My post | 2019-05-18 05:00:20 |
 -----------------------------------------
```

As you can see I get the entries twice (which is rather logical). So, how can I get rid of the duplicate entry?

Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, if I make the assumption that all translations have a greater post ID than the original post, then I can add a constraint `where t1.id>t2.id` and that gets rids of the duplicates.

Comment: Are there more than 2 translations?

Comment: Nope - only 2 - AND the original posts never have the same date.

Comment: Identifying posts by their timestamp is a bad idea. Who designed that schema?

Comment: No one at all - this is just a hack. The system isn't designed that way.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel if I did this the right way, I would look for the table that contains the mappings between posts

Comment: There is also no way to know which of two is the "original". Why is there no `lang` column? As I see, the problem is unsolvable, unless you find a way to determine the "original" post from the `post_name`, deriving the natural language from text.

Comment: The original is always the older one... I suppose I should just go dig deeper into their schema but given it's undocumented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `t1.post_name <> t2.post_name` you use `t1.post_name < t2.post_name` to get only one of the pairs. That, however, won't give you necessarily one language on the one side and the other on the other side. You'd need some measure to detect the languages to get that.

Also note that the comparison of the columns from `t1` and `t2` silently changes the `LEFT JOIN` effectively to an `INNER JOIN` so it's clearer to explicitly write it as such.

```
SELECT t1.post_name,
       t2.post_name,
       t1.post_date 
       FROM `posts` t1
            INNER JOIN `posts` t2
                       ON t1.post_date = t2.post_date 
       WHERE t1.post_status = 'publish'
             AND t1.post_type = 'post'
             AND t1.post_name < t2.post_name 
       ORDER BY t1.post_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the first post (by id) is the original and *all* have translations, then you can do:

```
SELECT p.post_name, pt.post_name, p.post_date 
FROM posts p JOIN
     posts pt
     ON pt.post_date = t2.post_date AND
        pt.id > p.id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' and 
      p.post_type = 'post' and 
      pt.post_status = 'publish' and 
      pt.post_type = 'post' 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, you can add categories to your post like english, french for each language. In this way you can group posts easily. I have added DATE_FORMAT to match the date of each post exactly to the date of another post(you can omit this if date and time are exactly same). I have added two more left joins to check if the category(language) is not the same. This way the query will give correct results. Then the query will become

```
SELECT t1.post_name, t2.post_name, t1.post_date, tr1.term_taxonomy_id, tr2.term_taxonomy_id
FROM `posts` t1 LEFT JOIN `posts` t2 ON date_format(t1.post_date, "%Y-%m-%d")  = date_format(t2.post_date, "%Y-%m-%d") left join `term_relationships` tr1 on  t1.ID=tr1.object_id left join `term_relationships` tr2 on t2.ID=tr2.object_id
WHERE t1.post_status='publish' and 
      t1.post_type='post' and
      t2.post_type='post' AND
      t2.post_status='publish' AND
      t1.post_name<>t2.post_name      
ORDER BY t1.post_date DESC
```

Comment: `date_format(t1.post_date, "%Y-%m-%d")` this is equivalent to `date(t1.post_date)`

Comment: Thank you. I mostly use date_format but date will also work.